# Spring cache default size

Tags: java, spring-boot, caching, spring-cache

What is the default size of spring cache ?
What happens if another entry comes which can be cached ? Does it ignore it or it removes an entry from cache to accommodate a new one ? If it deletes then how does it decide which one to delete ?

How can we provide a cache size manually ?
I am not referring to any other cache like Caffeine, EHCache etc.
I am referring the default spring cache.

Answer (score 3):

```
We can add our own expiry and max limit as follows :

 public CacheManager cacheManager() {
ConcurrentMapCacheManager cacheManager = new ConcurrentMapCacheManager() {
  @Override
  protected Cache createConcurrentMapCache(final String name) {
    return new ConcurrentMapCache(name, CacheBuilder.newBuilder().expireAfterWrite(7200,
        TimeUnit.SECONDS).maximumSize(500L).build().asMap(), false);
  }
};
```

Answer (score 2):

Spring's Cache Abstraction does not deal with the particular semantics and details of "managing" a cache's contents (such as as size, eviction or expiration policies). So all these settings must be define at the cache provider level(ehcache, hazelcast, infinispan..).

Default implementation of spring cache is a simple `ConcurrentHashMap`.

Comment: I actually does. We can build up the cache manager with defined values as below : new ConcurrentMapCacheManager() {
      @Override
      protected Cache createConcurrentMapCache(final String name) {
        return new ConcurrentMapCache(name, CacheBuilder.newBuilder().expireAfterWrite(7200,
            TimeUnit.SECONDS).maximumSize(500L).build().asMap(), false);
      }
    };

Comment: Yep as I said you should go to the detail provider  to define settings policies

Comment: You did not say that. You said "So all these settings must be define at the cache provider level(ehcache, hazelcast, infinispan..).". I am not using any of them. Thanks for your response

Comment: I didn't list all cache providers ;-) it is why I put ... after infinispan. Here what you've done is set these settings at the cache provider level (`ConcurrentMapCache` is used here so the cache provider is spring core). And to set these settings you had to define them at the cache implementation directly. So nothing done at the abstraction level ;-)